# How to remove unwanted String from Iframe(Span tag) it only show's in Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GQxT.png)
As i have marked in red this unwanted string show's up in the iframe in my chrome browser only
'''

```
$('iframe').load(function () {
    var $newText = $('iframe').contents().find(".newtext");
    $newText.replaceWith( $newText.text() )
});
```

'''

i used this code to remove the span tag